# How do I remove the last character from a string in R only if it is a letter?

Tags: r, regex

I have a column with the values such as this:

| Products |
| --- |
| 54632 |
| 54782L |
| 5847-46x |
| 7782M |

I want to create a new column with the same values as the original but I want to remove the last character only if its a Letter so the table would look like this

| Edited Products |
| --- |
| 54632 |
| 54782 |
| 5847-46 |
| 7782 |

Thank you

Comment: `df$Edited_Products <- sub('\\D$', '', df$Products)`

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_replace_all` with regular expression
`[A-Za-z]$ .... matches letter at the end

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Edited_Products = str_replace_all(Products, '[A-Za-z]$', ''))
```

```
  Edited_Products
1    54632
2    54782
3  5847-46
4     7782
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Products = c("54632", "54782L", "5847-46x", "7782M"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sub` with the regex `[A-Z]$` while ignoring case

```
df$Edited_Products <- sub('[A-Z]$', '', df$Products, ignore.case = TRUE)
df
  Products Edited_Products
1    54632           54632
2   54782L           54782
3 5847-46x         5847-46
4    7782M            7782
```